# Why ShowViaLink() doesn't work with Firefox or IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this simple page, navigation isn't working on Firefox or IE, only works on chrome.
I think it have to do with this as when i changed it, it stopped working on Firefox & IE:

```
// makes the navigation work after all containers have bee hidden 
        showViaLink($("aside button#navigation a"));
```

it was originally like that:

```
// makes the navigation work after all containers have bee hidden 
    showViaLink($("ul#navigation li a"));
```

However, I don't want to use ul li, Am i selecting it wrong?

Comment: IDs have to be unique! You should change that.

Comment: Do you know the meaning of word `unique`?

Comment: Every ID should appear only one time in your code. If you want to group elements do it by a `class`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
        <aside id="side">
            <div class="navigation"><a href="#home">Home</a> </div>
            <div class="navigation"><a href="#about"> About</a> </div>
            <div class="navigation"><a href="#contact"> Contact </a></div>
            <div class="navigation"><a href="#awards"> Awards </a></div>
            <div class="navigation"><a href="#links"> Links </a></div>
        </aside>
```

and alter this:

```
showViaLink($("aside .navigation a"));
```

In your old code you cant reach the lik, because you always push the button and so you never triggered `$(this).click(function()`

you just have to add some css and style your own buttons. [This generator](http://css3buttongenerator.com/) may be helpfull.

---

EDIT:

If you want to use die Buttons maybe this works:

```
<aside id="side">
  <div class="navigation" id="#home"><a href="#home">Home</a> </div>
  <div class="navigation" id="#about"><a href="#about"> About</a> </div>
  <div class="navigation" id="#contact"><a href="#contact"> Contact </a></div>
  <div class="navigation" id="#awards"><a href="#awards"> Awards </a></div>
  <div class="navigation" id="#links"><a href="#links"> Links </a></div>
</aside>
```

jQuery:

```
showViaLink($("aside .navigation"));

// shows proper DIV depending on link 'href'
function showViaLink(array)
{
    array.each(function(i)
    {   
        $(this).click(function()
        {
            var target = $(this).attr("id");
            $(".container").css("display","none");
            $(target).slideDown("slow");
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude you saved me days & it worked! can you provide how would i select css this way? because a previous answer from raina77ow got deleted advised something else, when i applied it nothing worked I think he sucks, I mean why delete it, anyways in css what does this button#navigation in CSS become?

Comment: ``#header button#navigation`` will be `#header div.navigation`

Comment: Yikes! Thanks dude :) You're awesome if I were an HR you'd be on my top 10 list of qualified developers.

Comment: Why can't i use  `button class="navigation"` instead of `div class="navigation"`

Comment: Because ``button`` and ``<a>`` both are clickable. If you click on it the button will work and you can never reach the ``<a>`` Look my edit above:

Comment: So I guess I'll just have to use div instead of button, I was considering Markup purposes, Anyways we got it done :) thanks again.